# indexing a numpy array to the last column

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

I'd like to replace the last N columns of a Numpy array by zeroes.

```
a = numpy.tile([1,2,3,4], (4,1))

array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

To replace the last, I do:

```
a[:,-1] = 0
```

To replace the last 2, I would do

```
a[:,-2:-1] = 0
```

but this only replaces the penultimate column

```
array([[1, 2, 0, 4],
       [1, 2, 0, 4],
       [1, 2, 0, 4],
       [1, 2, 0, 4]])
```

Can you please explain why? 
What should I do to get what I want?

Thanks

Comment: `a[:, -2:]`; use an open ended slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing `a[:,-2:-1] = 0` you are picking from the 1 before the last column, until the last column, **not including** the last column.

What you are looking for is `a[:,-2:] = 0` , which will pick all the columns from -2 to the end. Similarly, `a[:,-3:-1]` will pick the 2 middle columns.